# Do you need to roll tech attack for all tech actions?

Tags: lancer-rpg

In the core rulebook p. 79, it reads:

> TECH ATTACK: The statistic used to make tech attacks and to take most tech actions.

So from that, I understand that we have tech actions and some of them, most of them BUT not all of them require a tech attack throw.

The tech action (p. 70) "scan" and "lock on" doesn't mention any tech attack throw while for "invade" it does say that an attack roll is necessary.

In my group, *scan* and *lock on* are considered tech attack. Does someone knows which one it is?  Have we understood the rules correctly?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: It looks like you have accidentally created two accounts. If you complete registration (there should be a banner up top) and [get your accounts merged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) you'll be able to regain control of this one.

Answer (score 2):

### It doesn't say "make a tech attack", so you don't make a tech attack.

It might seem a little off that three out of the four Quick Tech options don't actually make tech attacks (Bolster doesn't either), but those are just the basic options. Other mechs have other attack options that count as Quick Tech.

This also means that Lock-On and Scan don't, for example, provoke counter-tech attacks from a Goblin, because they're not tech attacks.